# Symbolic trigonometry tool for graphically entered triangles

Tags: trigonometry

I am looking for a tool to solve or help solve a trigonometric problem symbolically.

I would like to enter the problem graphically (i.e. as a triangle drawing) and have it return the symbolic expressions for various dependent sides and angles.

I have found (online) tools for symbolic trigonometry problems, and I have found (online) tools for numerical evaluation of trigonometric angles and sides for a graphically entered triangle. In the latter you can change a side or angle and all others are numerically updated in the drawing.

But neither allows me to graphically enter a triangle, to add further bisections, projections etc... and return the symbolic expressions for the added sides and angles, based on complementary angles, Z/F angles etc...

For easy single triangle problems, a pen and paper sketch can be used to express various sides and angles using textbook cos/sin/tan equations. But when there are multiple dependent triangles this becomes more difficult, e.g. when one right angle triangle's base is another's hypothenuse.

Lacking such tool, what alternative approaches are there?